# Remove Item from ListView in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to bind a button click to one item in a ListView.ItemsSource such that an element is deleted (removed from the ItemsSource) without code behind?

Comment: use mvvm pattern .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by invoking a command of a view model that removes the item from an `ObservableCollection<T>` that the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` is bound to. This involves no code-behind logic in the view, but it does require to write a view model class in a programming language such as C# and set the `DataContext` of your `ListView` to an instance of this class.

There is no pure XAML solution to to do this, i.e. you will have to write some code. XAML is a *markup* language and it doesn't support removing elements from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes/No. Assign the operation to delete the item on the button using [Commanding in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview). Of course the logic of the command needs to be done in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

That's now possible in XAML using Behaviours...

```
<ListView  x:Name="aList">
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="blabla"/>
                        <Button Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="green">
                            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <b:RemoveItemInListBoxAction/>
                                </b:EventTrigger>
                            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            
            
        </ListView>
```